# Cordova/Ionic - How to remove external storage file and directory

Tags: file, cordova, ionic-framework

I have tried to delete the whole directory(the folder + files under the folder) which files were downloaded into the external storage base directory: cordova.file.externalDataDirectory(like"file///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.yourapp/files").

But when I tried to remove the directory recursively by $cordovaFile,like below:

```
  var baseDirectory = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + 'attachments';
  $cordovaFile.removeRecursively(baseDirectory,"")
      .then(function(success){
        console.log('Clear success');
      },function(err){
        loadingService.hideLoading();
   })
```

It throws NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED error:
[image: no_modification_allow_error]

While I check the folder permission, I do have the write/execute right. Any one has any idea why this happens?

BTW, I have also tried the window.requestFileSystem, unfortunately, still don't work out.Since the filesystem is local file system, I tried to change the entry to external file system like

```
entry.nativeURL = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
```

But I guess it won't work since the reader has nothing there. So anyone has any suggestions on how to remove the whole directory?

Thanks in advance!

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
    function fail(evt) {
      console.log("FILE SYSTEM FAILURE" + evt.target.error.code);
    }

    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
      fileSystem.root.getDirectory(
        "attachments",
        {create : true, exclusive : false},
        function(entry) {
          console.log(entry);
          entry.nativeURL = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
          var reader = entry.createReader();
          reader.readEntries(
            function(entries){
              console.log(entries);
            },
            function(err){
              console.log(err);
            }
          )

          entry.removeRecursively(function() {
           console.log('CLEAR success');
          }, fail);
        }, fail);
    }
```

Comment: any solution with error code 6>>

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Android Marshmallow, ensure to use latest version of cordova file plugin (4.2.0) as it has issues fixes related to permissions. The code snippet for directory deletion is as follows,

```
function clearDirectory() {
    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, onFileSystemDirSuccess, fail);
    } else {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemDirSuccess, fail);
    }

function onFileSystemDirSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var entry = "";
    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
        entry = fileSystem;
    } else {
        entry = fileSystem.root;
    }
    entry.getDirectory("DIRECTORY_TO_DELETE", {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
        },
        function(entry) {
            entry.removeRecursively(function() {
                console.log("Remove Recursively Succeeded");
            }, fail);
        }, getDirFail);
}

function getDirFail(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Error");
};

function fail(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Error");
};
```